# css animation not played after another class

Tags: css

I have a mini game of a deck of cards that when a card is clicked I have a css animation to flip the card over.

I have a second css `class` that I add with jQuery to animate the cards if they match. However when I add the second css `class` the animation does not play because of the first css animation `class`. If I was to remove the `class` `flip` the second animation will play but I cannot do this as I need to keep the `flip` class.

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    height: 6rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform .5s;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px 0px rgba(218,218,218,1);
}

.card:active {
    transform: scale(0.97);
    transition: transform .2s;
}

.card-face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Now when I add the `class` `.card-heartbeat` ti the element which already has the classes `card flip` nothing happens

```
.card-heartbeat {
    -webkit-animation: heartbeat 1.5s ease-in-out both;
            animation: heartbeat 1.5s ease-in-out both;
}

/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation heartbeat
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
@-webkit-keyframes card-heartbeat {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
            transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.91);
            transform: scale(0.91);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  17% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);
            transform: scale(0.98);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.87);
            transform: scale(0.87);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
@keyframes card-heartbeat {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
            transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.91);
            transform: scale(0.91);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  17% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);
            transform: scale(0.98);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.87);
            transform: scale(0.87);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
```

I am wondering is a clash of `transform`?

Answer (score 0):

adding `rotateY(180deg)` fixed the issue in the animation